# If I know the salt, can I decrypt the commitment?

Tags: encryption, salt

Say, I salt my key(K) with y. So, my new Key is K' = Salt(K+y). Now, Alice sends commitment = E[K',M] to Bob. Bob knows the salt(y), but not K nor K'. Can Bob decrypt the message?

Comment: Although this question is related to security, it is about the theoretical study of a cryptographic protocol, so it would be more at home [crypto.se]. I've flagged this question to ask a moderator to migrate it (do not repost).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if Bob only knows the salt, he should not be able to decrypt the message.  This is based on the assumption that the key can't be derived from the salt or some combination of the cipher text and the salt.  If that is the case, the salt would not be enough to recover the key.